# Springboot application @EnableConfigServer would not resolve in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm facing a rather odd issue which is I've set the necessary dependencies a mentioned in Spring documentation but once I add the `@EnableConfigServer` annotation Eclipse says it cannot be resolved. I checked the Maven dependencies folder and the necessary Spring Cloud Config *.jars were there. I tried deleting `.m2` directory and rebuilding project nothing seemed to work. Any idea on this would be great.

Comment: Do you generate your eclipse metadata using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` or do you use the m2e-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the pure eclipse issue.

Try cleaning the project once and check.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment/idea @Alien. I gave it another try by clearing `.m2` it resolved now. Maybe sometimes you need a little bit of luck as well.